# Closing an excel file without saving using pywin32: .Close(SaveChanges=False) method not working

Tags: excel, pywin32

I’m having an issue where my workbook (wb) still asks to save changes when running this part of my script:
wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)

It’s driving me crazy! Would someone be able to help (am running office 365)

Thanks

Comment: On my system wb.Close(SaveChanges=False) worked properly. Further, wb.Close(SaveChanges=True) also worked properly. My system: pywin32 version 303, Python 3.8.1, Win10, Office 365, Excel version 2201, Build 14827.20158. Perhaps more insight could be rendered by the community if you provide your code leading to the call to the Close() method. It may also help if you indicate your pywin32 version, python version, operating system, and excel build so they may be identified as, or eliminated from being, the problem.

Comment: You should be able to get the other system versions readily, but for the pywin32 version, on Windows open a command prompt and run the following command: pip list